# Install files (dependencies) into subfolder (lib) of the installation folder in Inno Setup

Tags: python, installation, inno-setup

Used **Inno Setup** to compile an installer with an executable I used from **cx_freeze**. My executable runs properly when I run it and I am absolutely positive I added all necessary dependencies from the executable file when setting up my installer using **Inno Setup Wizard**. Yet, I keep getting the following issue when I run my installed executable:
[image]

The following is the code to my **Inno Setup Compiler**:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Facile"
#define MyAppVersion "0.0.3"
#define MyAppPublisher "Facade Technologies, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "https://facade-technologies.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "facile.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{EAD17C54-8D79-446B-BF80-FFC1F4BC32BF}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\kirim
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\resources\facade_logo_256.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "armenian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Armenian.isl"
Name: "brazilianportuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"
Name: "catalan"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Catalan.isl"
Name: "corsican"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Corsican.isl"
Name: "czech"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Czech.isl"
Name: "danish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Danish.isl"
Name: "dutch"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Dutch.isl"
Name: "finnish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Finnish.isl"
Name: "french"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
Name: "hebrew"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Hebrew.isl"
Name: "icelandic"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Icelandic.isl"
Name: "italian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Italian.isl"
Name: "japanese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Japanese.isl"
Name: "norwegian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Norwegian.isl"
Name: "polish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Polish.isl"
Name: "portuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Portuguese.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"
Name: "slovak"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Slovak.isl"
Name: "slovenian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Slovenian.isl"
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"
Name: "turkish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Turkish.isl"
Name: "ukrainian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Ukrainian.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\facile.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\facile.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\python37.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

I've read similar post that hint something about the path not being specified for my installer or python not being able to find those modules . However, I do not know what to write and wear to write it. Like, would it be something I need to fix in my **setup.py** script for my executable or something I can fix in my **Inno Setup Compiler** script? Even more important, what do I need to change or write to get it running properly? Maybe, could it possibly be because of where I decided to save my .exe that is installed with **mysetup.exe**? Anything helps, thank you!

***Update***

I think I may have figured out my issue. Before, I wasn't installing the folders from my .exe folder that contained all the dependencies, I was adding them as files and not folders. Now I am adding those folders as folders, but there's still an issue because I am not installing the folders properly. I need to maintain the same file structure in my installed .exe folder as the .exe folder I built on my computer. Here is an example line of code to add a folder to my installed .exe folder in my script:

```
Source: "C:\Users\kirim\Documents\Facade Technologies\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\lib\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

The issue is that it installs all the folders and files contained within that folder but not the folder itself, so I can keep the same file structure(for example my script isn't install **lib** folder it's install everything contained in the folder which changes the file structure set for the exe's source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install files into subfolder of the installation folder, you have to specify the folder in the `DestDir` parameter:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\...\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\facile.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\...\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\lib\*"; DestDir: "{app}\lib"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

---

Or, if the build folder contains only the files you want to distribute, include it whole:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\...\facile\build\exe.win32-3.7\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue. I don't know how I didn't think of focusing on the `DestDir` parameter!